# Arduino ultrasonic sensor value is not 0 and cannot change value if there's an object in front of the ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino

I have 3 ultrasonic sensors and the problem is the value it's reading is not 0, it's something like 1606, 1602 and 1619.

Another problem is the value is not changing when I put an object in front of the sensors.

The code I'm using is like this:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClient.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin_1 = D1; 
const int echoPin_1 = D0; 

const int trigPin_2 = D6;  
const int echoPin_2 = D5;  

const int trigPin_3 = D7;  
const int echoPin_3 = D8;  


String uri = "http://192.168.0.128/socketprogramming/client.php";

// defines variables
long duration_1;
int distance_1;

long duration_2;
int distance_2;


long duration_3;
int distance_3;

WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
 // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  //Serial.println();
 for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("TP-LINK_86AC", "79043120");
 // wifiMulti.addAP("secondary-network-name", "pass-to-secondary-network");
  //wifiMulti.addAP("tertiary-network-name", "pass-to-tertiary-network");

  pinMode(trigPin_1, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin_1, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input

  pinMode(trigPin_2, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin_2, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input

  pinMode(trigPin_3, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin_3, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
}



void ultrasonic(int type){

  if(type == 1){ 

      digitalWrite(trigPin_1, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(2);

      // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
      digitalWrite(trigPin_1, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(10);
      digitalWrite(trigPin_1, LOW);

      // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
      duration_1 = pulseIn(echoPin_1, HIGH);

      // Calculating the distance
      distance_1= duration_1;
      // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
      Serial.print("Ultrasonic 1: ");
      Serial.println(distance_1);

      String data = String("?type=") + "1" + "&level="+ distance_1 + "&deviceID=" + 1;

      if (http.begin(uri + data)) 
      {  // HTTP

        int httpCode = http.GET();

        // httpCode will be negative on error
        if (httpCode > 0) {
          // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
          Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

          // file found at server
          if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
              String payload = http.getString();
              Serial.println(payload);
          }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();     
      delay(1000);
  }
 }

  if(type == 2){ 

       digitalWrite(trigPin_2, LOW);
       delayMicroseconds(2);

       // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
       digitalWrite(trigPin_2, HIGH);
       delayMicroseconds(10);
       digitalWrite(trigPin_2, LOW);

       // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
       duration_2 = pulseIn(echoPin_2, HIGH);

       // Calculating the distance
       distance_2= duration_2*0.034/2;
       // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
       Serial.print("Ultrasonic 2: ");
       Serial.println(distance_2);

       String data = String("?type=") + "2" + "&level="+ distance_2 + "&deviceID=" + 1;

      if (http.begin(uri + data)) 
      {  // HTTP

        int httpCode = http.GET();

        // httpCode will be negative on error
        if (httpCode > 0) {
          // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
          Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

          // file found at server
          if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
            String payload = http.getString();
              Serial.println(payload);

          }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();     
      delay(1000);
   }
  }

  if(type == 3){


     digitalWrite(trigPin_3, LOW);
     delayMicroseconds(2);

     // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
     digitalWrite(trigPin_3, HIGH);
     delayMicroseconds(10);
     digitalWrite(trigPin_3, LOW);

     // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
      duration_3 = pulseIn(echoPin_3, HIGH);

      // Calculating the distance
      distance_3= duration_3*0.034/2;
      // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
      Serial.print("Ultrasonic 3: ");
      Serial.println(distance_3);

      String data = String("?type=") + "3" + "&level="+ distance_3 + "&deviceID=" + 1;

      if (http.begin(uri + data)) 
      {  // HTTP

        int httpCode = http.GET();

        // httpCode will be negative on error
        if (httpCode > 0) {
          // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
          Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

          // file found at server
          if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            Serial.println(payload);
          }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();     
      delay(1000);
   }
  }

}

void loop()
{

  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) 
   {
      Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
      ultrasonic(1);
      ultrasonic(2);
      ultrasonic(3);

    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
    }
  //.run();
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but your ultrasonic function massively duplicates code. You can simplify your function, look at this paste: https://www.paste.org/100409

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code for your first ultrasonic sensor. This is what you wrote: `distance_1= duration_1;`
You are setting the distance by the amount of time it took to get the reflected wave back. You forgot to multiply the duration with 0.034 and divide it by 2.
Use this code instead:

```
  duration_1 = pulseIn(echoPin_1, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance_1= duration_1*0.034/2;
  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Ultrasonic 1: ");
  Serial.println(distance_1);
```